# Reading the APP.config in/after a foreach loop of IEnumerable objects removes the items from collection

Tags: c#, wpf

Encountered a strange error, any one knows about this?

I have a foreach loop of IEnumerable objects, inside the loop I am updating a value in my configuration file and reading the value back. When the value is read back the object that is processed is been removed from the collection. No exception was thrown but by the end of the loop there is no items inside.

```
Objs = Objs.SkipWhile(j => j.Id != ConfigValues.LastInvoiceJobID)

private async Task MyFunction(IEnumerable<MyObj> Objs)
{
    MyObj JobInProcess = null;
    foreach (MyObj item in Objs)
    {
        JobInProcess = item;

        //DO SOME PROCESSING

        //UPDATE CONFIG
        Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);                    
        config.AppSettings.Settings["LastInvoiceJobID"].Value = JobInProcess.Id;
        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");

        //READ BACK THE CONFIG VALUES TO STATIC VARIABLES OF A CLASS
    }
}
```

I Have tried skipping of "READ BACK THE CONFIG VALUES TO STATIC VARIABLES OF A CLASS" then the collection is not modifying.

EDIT:
Even if i try to read the appsettings outside the loop, processed elements are removed from IEnumerable collection.

What can be the reason?

Comment: You seem to use some concurrency here. Have you tried to use `lock` for your "update config" part?

Comment: There is no multiple threads here. Further to add, even if i read the config after the loop, same issue happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue.

I was creating the IEnumerable using a linq expression without .ToList(). This makes the collection auto refresh when the condition is updated dynamically.

```
//there was no ToList
//ConfigValues.LastInvoiceJobID comes from App config value
Objs = Objs.SkipWhile(j => j.Id != ConfigValues.LastInvoiceJobID);
MyFunction(Objs);
```

Once i update the configuration value, the same is used in the linq expression.
This makes the collection to be updated based on the condition.

Solution is to add ToList

```
Objs = Objs.SkipWhile(j => j.Id != ConfigValues.LastInvoiceJobID).ToList();
```